# Why $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{C}) = Pic(X) \otimes \mathbb{C}$ for Calabi-Yau 3-folds?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a Calabi-Yau 3-fold, that is $\omega_X = 0$ and $h^{1,0}=h^{2,0}=0$. Let $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ be the group of line bundles on $X$. Then why the following isomorphism is true $$H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{C}) = \operatorname{Pic}(X) \otimes \mathbb{C}.$$

It seems that this is only true for Calabi-Yau 3-folds, rather than arbitrary Calabi-Yau variety or 3-folds?

Comment: Hint: use the exponential SES and Serre duality to show that $Pic(X) \cong H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ where $Pic(X) \cong H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^{\star}).$ Now, tensor both sides by $\otimes \mathbb{C}$ and use Hodge (cohomology) decomposition to get $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})\cong H^{1,1}(X).$

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean! First, use $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}^*_X \to 0$ to show $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X^*) \cong H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. Then $ H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ by universal coefficient theorem. Then the Hodge decomposition gives $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{C}) \cong H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ because of CY condition. Am I right?

Comment: yes, that's right. Now, fill the gaps!

Comment: @LiYutong: You should expand your comment into an answer.